# how to make Visual Studio stop at my code other than an asm file when run a dmp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Windows App exits, when I use Visual Studio 2017 to parse dmp, it jumps into a library (`QtGui`) asm file and points at the exception location like this:
[image: exception location]

It is helpless for me to locate the problem in my code. Instead of an asm file, is it possible for me to have Visual Studio points at my source code?

Comment: Switch the "Stack Frame" on the Debug toolbar to your code.

Comment: Since the exception is in a routine that checks the stack it likely indicates a problem with the stack. I am not sure if this indicates stack overflow or corruption.